How does Windows' Game controller properties connect to a joystick?
The situation:
We need to use a new game controller (with a joystick only) hardware on Windows IoT. In the properties of "Game Controllers", moving the joystick is visible in the displayed square with the '+'. Our software using DirectX8 API only reads 0 values for x/y axes.
What I've tried so far:

DirectX8 obviously doesn't work, also, it's deprecated
Using Gaming.Input: not an option, we have no UWP
XInput: not an option, we have no XBox (compatible) device
Using joyGetPosEx from MultiMediaSystem: doesn't work

The question: Obviously Windows somehow can "see" the controller and also recognizes the joystick movements; so what API do they use in this little "Game Controllers" window?
Any other suggestion on how to read joystick data?

You may want to post to [gamedev.se].
